# How to deactivate jnativehook on demand?

Tags: java, jnativehook

If my understanding serves me correct jnativehook can be turned on and off with these two commands:

> GlobalScreen.removeNativeKeyListener(this); //this shuts it down
>
> GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(this);//and this turns it back on again

by this logic the program below:

```
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;

import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class GlobalKeyListenerExample implements NativeKeyListener {

public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {


    System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    String s = NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode());
    handle(s);




    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalScreen.class.getPackage().getName());
    logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);


    logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
    if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_ESCAPE) {
        try {
            GlobalScreen.unregisterNativeHook();
        } catch (NativeHookException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
}

public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Key Typed: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
}






public void handle(String k) {
    if (k == "A") {//close nativeKeylistener and execute run()
        GlobalScreen.removeNativeKeyListener(this);
        run();

        run2();//turn keylistener back on
    }

}

public void run() {
    System.out.println("Hello there!");
    System.out.print("Write something, please: ");
    Scanner lukija = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = lukija.nextLine();
    System.out.println("you wrote: "+str);
}

public void run2() {
    GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(this);

}





public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalScreen.class.getPackage().getName());
    logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);


    logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
    try {
        GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
    } catch (NativeHookException ex) {
        System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

        System.exit(1);
    }

    GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(new GlobalKeyListenerExample());
}

}
```

It should print something like this, by my understanding.

```
kKey Pressed: K
Key Pressed: J
jKey Pressed: G
gKey Pressed: U
uKey Pressed: Y
yKey Pressed: T
tKey Pressed: H
hKey Pressed: V
vKey Pressed: B
bKey Pressed: N
nKey Pressed: H
hKey Pressed: G
gKey Pressed: A
Hello there!
Write: i am a robot
i am a robot
```

Instead i get this:

```
kKey Pressed: K
Key Pressed: J
jKey Pressed: G
gKey Pressed: U
uKey Pressed: Y
yKey Pressed: T
tKey Pressed: H
hKey Pressed: V
vKey Pressed: B
bKey Pressed: N
nKey Pressed: H
hKey Pressed: G
gKey Pressed: A
Hello there!
Write: i am a robot
i am a robot
Key Pressed: Backspace
Key Pressed: I
Key Pressed: Space
Key Pressed: A
Hello there!
Write: test
test
Key Pressed: M
Key Pressed: Space
Key Pressed: A
Hello there!
Write: test
test
Key Pressed: Space
Key Pressed: R
Key Pressed: O
Key Pressed: B
Key Pressed: O
Key Pressed: T
Key Pressed: Enter
Key Pressed: T
Key Pressed: E
Key Pressed: S
Key Pressed: T
Key Pressed: Enter
Key Pressed: T
Key Pressed: E
Key Pressed: S
Key Pressed: T
```

What happens is that nativehook keeps rergistering all the inputs even tho i have used the command

> GlobalScreen.removeNativeKeyListener(this);

and when i add it back it with run2(), the program goes through all the key presses i gave it while giving input(and the methods they invoke, in this case run() when "a" is pressed). Why this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You remove the key listener but that doesn't stop the library from logging keystrokes.

To stop logging you shall do:

```
GlobalScreen.unregisterNativeHook();
```

Comment: Yeah, i looked into that but that also closes the program, so i can't use GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();.